# Linq to XML: create an anonymous object with element attributes and values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm new to Linq and I'm trying to query a XML document to find a list of account managers for a particular user. (I realize it might make more sense to put this in a database or something else, but this scenario calls for a XML document).

```
<user emailAddress='user@fabrikam.com'>
    <accountManager department='Customer Service' title='Manager'>manager@fabrikam.com</accountManager>
    <accountManager department='Sales' title='Account Manager'>manager@fabrikam.com</accountManager>
    <accountManager department='Sales' title='Account Manager'>manager@fabrikam.com</accountManager>
</user>
```

I trying to create a list of objects (anonymous type?) with properties consisting of both XElement attributes (department, title) and values (email). I know that I can get either of the two, but my problem is selecting both.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
var managers = _xDoc.Root.Descendants("user")
               .Where(d => d.Attribute("emailAddress").Value == "user@fabrikam.com")
               .SelectMany(u => u.Descendants("accountManager").Select(a => a.Value));

foreach (var manager in managers)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

I can get at `a.Value` and `a.Attribute` but I can't figure out how to get both *and* store them in an object. I have a feeling it would wind up looking something like:

```
select new { 
    department = u.Attribute("department").Value,
    title = u.Attribute("title").Value,
    email = u.Value
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  It would look exactly like that.

For example:

```
_xDoc.Root.Descendants("user")
          .Where(d => d.Attribute("emailAddress").Value == "user@fabrikam.com")
          .SelectMany(u => u.Descendants("accountManager"))
          .Select(a => new { 
              department = a.Attribute("department").Value,
              title = a.Attribute("title").Value,
              email = a.Value
          });
```

**EDIT**: Using query comprehension syntax:

```
from u in _xDoc.Root.Descendants("user")
where u.Attribute("emailAddress").Value == "user@fabrikam.com"
from a in u.Descendants("accountManager")
select new { 
               department = a.Attribute("department").Value,
               title = a.Attribute("title").Value,
               email = a.Value
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return anonymous type from a `Select` method you can write:

```
var managers = 
  _xDoc.Root.Descendants("user") 
       .Where(d => d.Attribute("emailAddress").Value == "user@fabrikam.com") 
       .SelectMany(u => 
          u.Descendants("accountManager")
           .Select(a => new {  
              Department = u.Attribute("department").Value, 
              Title = u.Attribute("title").Value, 
              Email = u.Value })
        );
```

The syntax for creating anonymous types isn't directly bound to the `select` keyword. You can use it for example like this:

```
var manager = new { Department = "Somewhere", Title = "Mr" };
```

So, the syntax `a => new { ... }` is a lambda expression that returns a new anonymous type, just like `select new { ... }` is a clause that constructs new anonymous type.

Regarding the choice between dot-notation and query syntax - this is really a personal preference (although some things look better with the query syntax and some methods such as `Count` can be used only using dot-notation). However, all queries all translated to method calls by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there's only a single user with `sipAddress == sipUri`?

Let's start with this:

```
var managers = _xDoc.Root
```

You can select just the first element that match by using `.First`

```
.First(d => d.Attribute("sipAddress").Value == sipUri)
```

This will gets the first user where the predicate returns true. Then, you'll want to extract both the attributes and the values in the element into a new object (anonymous type).

If there're many users and you want *all* the listed managers, this can be done by using `.SelectMany` (i.e. for each users, there're many managers, select all of them) but in this case I assume there's only one, and `.First` has returned that very element so you can just use its properties to access the list of managers

```
.Descendants("accountManager")
```

Then you'll get all the `XElement` descending from the selected element. Transforming it into another object by using the values from the elements is done by using a mapping function which, in Linq, is `.Select`

```
.Select(managerElem => new {
    department = u.Attribute("department").Value,
    title = u.Attribute("title").Value,
    email = u.Value 
});
```

As I've said earlier, if there're multiple users with the correct `sipAddress` and you want *all* the managers, just wrap the `.Descendants` inside `.SelectMany`.

```
.SelectMany(userElem => userElem.Descendants("accountManager"))
```

I havn't tested the code but I believe you'll be able to figure it out by following what I've written.

Hope this helps! :) Feel free to ask in the comments if you're still confused.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, great help. I'm still learning.